# AVEVA Wonderware Failed to deploy <Platform_Name>, Remote Node's UserId/Password don't match GR Node's

Tags: deployment, ide, wonderware

While Deploying the Platform , i am facing following error.

Error: Failed to deploy <Platform_Name> : Remote Node's UserId/Password don't match GR Node's.

Answer (score 1):

Run the `Change Network Account` utility on both machines and reboot. It sounds like the service account Wonderware uses to communicate between nodes doesn't have matching credentials.

Comment: This is the answer ... credentials must match on all nodes.